# Generate apk file from playground online

Tags: android, apk, nativescript

I have written a small test app on nativescript playground online, and I want .apk file of it. Is there any online tool to generate .apk file from playground, instead of having to install tns and run 'tns run'/'tns debug'/'tns build' on my local machine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to generate APK from Playground.

If you don't want to setup Android SDK locally, you may try cloud build option but at least that requires NativeScript CLI / Sidekick setup on your local machine.

Comment: Thanks, but will i get the .apk file after cloud build ?

Comment: Yes, you would get the APK on cloud build.

Comment: I tried cloud build from NS Sidekick, but it throws this error, "Build failed. zlib: unexpected end of file"

Comment: That totally depends on your project and setup. I would suggest you to raise a separate question with all required details like a complete error log, content of `package.json`.